# How to use Exception filters in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

How i can implement Exception Filters in MVC5.

I want to throw the exception to NLog and redirect the page to a default error page which displays "Something is gone wrong"

I have a Filter class as follows

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Delivros.UI.Controllers;
using Delivros.UI.Areas.User.ViewModel;
using System.Web;

namespace Delivros.UI.Filters
{

public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationChallenge : MyAuthenticationFilter");
    }
}
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Convert.ToString(CookieField.cookieName)]] == null)
        {

        }
        else
{
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary 
    {
                { "controller", "User" }, 
                { "action", "UserRegistration" } ,
                {"Area","User"}
            });

        }
    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
              new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "controller", "User" }, 
                { "action", "UserRegistration" } ,
                {"Area","User"}
            });
        // ActionResult home = new HomeController().Index();           
    }
}

public class MyResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}

public class MyExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
              new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "controller", "User" }, 
                { "action", "UserLogOut" } ,
                {"Area","User"}
            });

    }
}
```

}

But nothing is redirecting to the page...

Answer (score 21):

You could derive your own [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
public class NLogExceptionHandlerAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // log error to NLog
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then register it globally

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new NLogExceptionHandlerAttribute());
    ...
}
```

By default, the `HandleErrorAttribute` will display the `Error` view located in the `~/Views/Shared` folder but if you wanted to display a specific view you can set the `View` property of the attribute.

Comment: Where should i put this class NLogExceptionHandlerAttribute ?

Comment: @SajnaAli it's just an attribute, same as all other attributes in MVC therefore it can be placed against an action, controller or you can register it globally (which is what you seem to want). I have provided an example of how you do that.

Comment: There is already a line in application_start in global.asax
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

should we add the line you mentioned above in global.asax file?

it showing errors

Comment: @SajnaAli no, go to your `FilterConfig.cs` file and add the line above in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method.

Comment: It showing error on "The kyword is "New" is reqiured on "OnException" because it hides method "void System.Web.MVC.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)

Comment: The naming convention is right? For filters is should end with "filter", right? or Attribute?

Comment: @SajnaAli oops, `virtual` should have been `override`, see update.

Comment: What i have done right now is created a file named `NLogExceptionHandlerAttribute`  in Filters with the contents as you specified and in `FilterConfig.cs` i added the filter. Then in Controller i have applied the filter as follows: `[NLogExceptionHandler]
        public ActionResult UserRegistration()
        {             }`

Comment: I have modified the filter class as follows to include my Nlog    
    `public class NLogExceptionHandlerAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        private static readonly NLogLogger Logger = new NLogLogger();

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext     filterContext)
        {
            // log error to NLog
            Logger.Error("An error has occurred", filterContext.Exception);
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }`

Comment: @now everything is working fine. But how can i redirect to a default error page? I had set the following code in webconfig but the same page loading when the error occurs. not redirecting
`<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="432" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"/>
    </customErrors>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be this code:

```
public class MyExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
            action = "UserLogOut", 
            controller = "User", 
            area = "User" 
        }));

    }
```

}

You may add an additional "if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)" statement before logging the values inside the result to make sure that the exception's unhandled for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Exception filters are run only when unhandled  exception has been thrown inside an action method. As you asked, here is an example to redirect to another page upon exception:

```
public class MyExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Content/ErrorPage.html");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }    
    }
}
```

Now, to apply this filter to either controllers or individual actions, put [MyException] on them.

You may need to check the occurence of an specific Exception inside the if clause.
e.g.:

```
if(... && filterContext.Excaption is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
```

To return a View as Exception Response:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/ErrorAction");
```

other alternatives you might use to redirect are:

- new RedirectToRouteResult{ ... }
- new ViewResult{ ... }

Comment: this example is for WebApi 2.0

Comment: sorry, you're wrong. Exception filters applied to controllers (either API or a general controller) in the same manner.   you can refer to this link (https://books.google.com/books?id=ZqZ4AgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) Chapter 18, Exception Filters

Comment: sorry you are wrong, your example works for MVC for dotnet core, but not for classic WebApi

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. A few things to note 1) RedirectResult points to a controller action, not a view 2) you need to set filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true; or your exception view / page will not display.

```
public class ErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error(filterContext.Exception, "An Unhandled exeption occured durring the execution of a request");

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/MyControler/MyErrorAction");
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

}
```

Ofcourse you will also need to register the Error attribute using the GlobalFilters object from your Global.asax as shown below.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ErrorAttribute());           
     ...
 }
```