# Returning Complex JSON from Azure App Service

Tags: json, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a running .NET WebApi on Microsoft Azure. When tested locally using fiddler or postman, all endpoints work and return json data as expected. However, when published to azure, I've realized endpoints returning nested json array within arrays return internal server error. I have tried inspecting the FREB logs and other possible error logs, but no useful explanation seen anywhere.

Below are pictures of the json i"m trying to return and a screenshot from the Azure FREB logs.

[image]

[image]

FREB Logs Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @David Makogon, any idea on this one?

Comment: You can catch exception and return it instead of normal response, or use Error filer as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201795/how-to-use-exception-filters-in-mvc-5

Comment: thanks @mikalai, dont know why id didnt think of that, Just used a try catch to return the actual exception in the response object